# MyObjectBox is red/not found but Java app still works

Tags: java, objectbox

I'm trying to use ObjectBox in a simple java server side app.

Everything is working fine, I'm putting things in boxes etc, but the MyObjectBox class is always red when I use it.

I can see the generated .class and .java files, along with the meta _ classes, in build/classes/main/db (db is the package name I have in my actual code), but for some reason I can't import MyObjectBox.

Because of this, I also can't import the _ classes for use in Queries, which now kind of prevents me from getting any further.

My code to use objectBox is inside a class called DB which I have copied below, in case there's anything I'm doing wrong with that.

But as it actually works, I'm very confused!!

Thanks

UPDATE: if I run gradle clean build, my app runs fine, if I run Build->Build Project in intelliJ then I get the error

```
Error:(27, 21) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable MyObjectBox
  location: class DB
```

.

```
package db;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import io.objectbox.Box;
import io.objectbox.BoxStore;

public class DB {

    private File boxStoreDir;
    private static BoxStore store;

    public DB() {
        try {
            createMyObjectBox();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void createMyObjectBox() throws IOException {
        File objectstorefile = new File("../objectBox/objectstorefile");
        if(!objectstorefile.isDirectory()) {
            objectstorefile.mkdirs();
        }
        boxStoreDir = objectstorefile;

        if(store == null) {
            store = MyObjectBox.builder().directory(boxStoreDir).build();
        }
    }

    public<T> Box<T> getBox(Class<T> object) {
        if(store == null) {
            try {
                createMyObjectBox();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return store.boxFor(object);
    }
}
```

Comment: Fixed it! Was missing the `apply plugin: 'net.ltgt.apt-idea'` even though I'd added the classpath for it! Doh

Answer (score 1):

Forget the `apply plugin: 'net.ltgt.apt-idea'` in build.gradle